# The ECS servive with aws_vpc cannot start due to ENI issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, network-interface

I have got one service. I have ECS cluster with 2 instances of t3.small.

I cannot start the ECS task. I have ECS task with 2 containers(NGINX and PHP-FPM). NGINX exposes port 80 and PHP-FPM exposes ports 9000, 9001, 9002.

Error I can see:

```
dev-cluster/ecs-agents i-12345678901234567 2019-09-15T13:20:48Z [ERROR] Task engine [arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:123456789012:task/ea1d6e4b-ff9f-4e0a-b77a-1698721faa5c]: unable to configure pause container namespace: cni setup: invoke bridge plugin failed: bridge ipam ADD: failed to execute plugin: ecs-ipam: getIPV4AddressFromDB commands: failed to get available ip from the db: getAvailableIP ipstore: failed to find available ip addresses in the subnet
```

ECS agent: 1.29.

Do you know How Can I figure out what is wrong?

Here is logs snippet: https://pastebin.com/my620Kip

Task definition: https://pastebin.com/C5khX9Zy

### UPDATE: My observations

Edited because my post below was deleted...

I recreated cluster, then the problem disappears. 
Then I removed the application image from the ECR and I was seeing an error in AWS web console:

`CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: manifest for 123456789123.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/application123:development-716b4e55dd3235f6548d645af9e463e744d3785f not found`

Then I waited a few hours until the original issue happened again. 
Then I restarted instance manually with `systemctl reboot` and the problem disappeared again only for restarted instance.

This issue appears when On the cluster is hundred(s) awsvpc task which cannot start.

I think this is a bug in ECS agent. And When We are trying to create too many containers with requires ENI it is trying to use all free IPs in the subnet. (255) I think after restart/recreate EC2 instance some cache is cleared and the problem is solved.

Here is similar solution I found today: https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cni-plugins/issues/93#issuecomment-502099642

What do you think about it?

I am opened for suggestions.

Comment: Seems like bridges network is attached in task definitions? Fargate only work in awsvpc network

Comment: I have another awsvpc task which is working with EC2. Only this cannot start.

Comment: Why do you have no mappings definitions for the app?

Comment: Because I do not expose it out of the application environment. In the nginx, I use localhost:9000 as an upstream. It's Ok because AWS guarantee that whole task definition is started on one instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just a wild guess, but can it be that you simply don't have enough ENIs?

ENIs are quite limited (depending on the instance type):

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html

For instance, `t3.medium` only has 3 ENIs, one of which is used for primary network interface. Which leaves you with 2 ENIs only. So I can imagine that ECS tasks fail to start due to insufficient ENIs.

As mitigation, try ENI trunking:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-instance-eni.html

This will multiply available ENIs per instance.

Comment: My instances have 3 ENIs, I have 2 tasks on the cluster which requires ENIs. Both T3.small and T3.medium have got 3 ENIs.
My cluster has got 2 instances = 6 ENIs. 2 ENIs are used for Primary Network Interfaces => 4 interfaces left.
One ENI is used for another service (aws_vpc), 3 interfaces left.

When this service cannot start any container and I kill another running service with aws_vpc, the second one cannot start still. 

This is a global problem.